# Javascript Dynamically adding text boxes with value

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new to javascript. I am trying to add multiple text box dynamically on run time..

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ajax(){
                var x = document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML;
                x= x + '<input name="reference[]" type="text" />';
                document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = x;
            }
        </script>
```

This is an on click event. Here my problem is that every time add a new text box the value of my previous text box disappears and an all the text boxes are empty each time the function is called.

Comment: Despite the minimal attempt of HTML5 to standardise innerHTML, it is inconsistent across browsers, especially regarding attributes and properties. Do not rely on it for non-trivial purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement) and [`document.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild)

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkwJz/)

```
function ajax() {
    var textBox = document.createElement('input');
    textBox.name = 'reference[]';
    textBox.type = 'text';
    document.getElementById("ajax").appendChild(textBox);
}
```

Comment: yeah thats the right way to add elements to page... not to append some html text string

Answer (score 0):

Append to existing content not overwriting it

Append:

```
document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML += x;
```

Overwrite

```
document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = x;
```

Use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function ajax(){
                var x = '<input name="reference[]" type="text" />';
                document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML += x;
            }
</script>
```

Comment: DOM does not recommend same name for two elements. But using JQuery, (change reference[] to reference) u can get the values with selector $("#reference"). If you want these values on server side, which language you are using?

Comment: not sure on php, check this http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=31836

Comment: @hungryMind - there is nothing wrong with giving multiple elements the same name where it is specified as an attribute in the HTML standard. Please provide a reference where "DOM" says otherwise.